# How do I convert a UIImage to NSData or CFDataRef?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage

How do I convert a `UIImage` to `NSData` or `CFDataRef`? I need to pass a `CFDataRef` to `ABPersonSetImageData`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This worked for me, for a PNG image. For other image types, I assume you just have to find the corresponding UIImage...Representation method.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName.png"];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)];
```

If you need a CFDataRef for a UIImage, it's just one more line.

```
CFDataRef imgDataRef = (CFDataRef)imageData;
```

Comment: Why are you using `+[NSData dataWithData:]`?

Comment: Touché. I suppose you could just do `NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);`

Answer (score 7):

you can use this

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
```

and simply cast imageData to `CFDataRef`

```
CFDataRef = (CFDataRef) imageData;
```

Comment: NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0); is very slow also equivalent png method. Is there any fast way???????

Answer (score 3):

```
CFDataRef cfdata = CFDataCreate(NULL, [imageData bytes], [imageData length]);
```

For a working example click [here](http://ddchettige.blogspot.com/2011/08/from-nsdata-to-cfdataref.html).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For those who wondering what is difference between `NSData` and `CFData`, here is the explanation from [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/cfdata-rv9):

> CFData is “toll-free bridged” with its Cocoa Foundation counterpart,
> NSData. What this means is that the Core Foundation type is
> interchangeable in function or method calls with the bridged
> Foundation object. In other words, in a method where you see an NSData
> * parameter, you can pass in a CFDataRef, and in a function where you see a CFDataRef parameter, you can pass in an NSData instance. This
> also applies to concrete subclasses of NSData. See Toll-Free Bridged
> Types for more information on toll-free bridging.

This explains why casting `NSData` to `CFData` works.